# QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt5, qgraphicsview

I have a doubt with QGraphicsView. If i put the scenes with coordinates: (0,0,200,200), the scene decreases of 9px from top e 9px from the left, like in the image:

[image]

```
QGraphicsScene *myScene= new QGraphicsScene();
CustomAnimation *ca = new CustomAnimation(); //inherits from QGraphicsWidget
myScene->addItem(ca);
myScene->setSceneRect(0,0,200,200);
ui->gfx_animation->setScene(myScene);
ui->gfx_animation->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->gfx_animation->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

but if I use setSceneRect (9,9,200,200), the scene is properly positioned. Something wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to clean your project once and then compile it again. Clean option is under the Build menu in Qt creator.

Comment: no, i tried it, but i have the same result